# Select all cells in column B where Column A in that row contains a specific text

Tags: excel, formatting

Basically I have a price list where I want to average the price of all the items on the list that contain my keyword.
The keyword is `keyword`, price column is B and item description in which to look for `keyword` is in column A.
I'd like to have a formula like
=Average(data_table,all cell B from row i (i,B) where (i,A) contains `keyword`)

To Simplify, I added a picture. I tried the suggested solutions below but none worked. I should get 15.33 (Assuming the indices go from 1 to 5 and not from 2 to 5 as in the picture)

[image]

Comment: [AVERAGEIF](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/averageif-function-HA010047433.aspx)

Comment: Can there be other text in the cell, or is "keyword" by itself?

Comment: Doesnt have to be by itself

Comment: How do I do it if the criterion (item description) cell is dynamic? i.e for every price it needs to check whether the desciption cell in its row contains the keyword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `AVERAGEIF`, which I believe became available in Excel 2007. This will handle "keyword" by itself, or as part of a longer string like "my keyword".

`=AVERAGEIF(A2:A5,"*keyword*",B2:B5)`

To refer to a cell containing a keyword, D1 in this example, use:

`=AVERAGEIF(A2:A5,"*" & D1 & "*",B2:B5)`

Comment: Try reversing A and B columns.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(B:B,A:A,"*"&"keyword"&"*")
```

Cheers!

**::Edit for Updated Question::**

With your new layout, use the following:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(B1:B5,"*"&D1&"*",A1:A5)
```

Comment: Although, this can also be written as =AVERAGEIFS(B:B,A:A,"*keyword*") where 'stars' (although you can't see them in this comment as they denote italicized text) are inserted on either side of *keyword*.  I got a little excited there and hit post too quickly.  Either will work. :)

Comment: So... how did I answer the original question TWO minutes AFTER I commented on MY OWN ANSWER (with an update for another way to specify the "keyword")???